# Thread freeze and click

Tags: c#, tcp

i have a window with tcp connection. When i await to response window freeze.(Unfreeze after get response) It's okay. But when it wait and i click on button again, after first freeze comes second with again waiting to response.

Comment: Are you by chance re-attaching the event, so you have the event fire more than once?

Comment: Maybe but i want to know it is someway able to do it only once.

Comment: Try wiring up the event to the method that it calls in the Form_Load method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/Cc221403(v=VS.95).aspx).

With that, your form should not freeze.